# jquery help needed for function to run first

Tags: jquery, click

Hello i have a script

```
<script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
                test();
            jQuery('#bf_dishes > li > a').live('click', function(e) {
                    alert('HI');
                        i=1;
                        var kitchenname=$(this).parent('li').index();

                        $('.bf_gallery_item').each(function() {
                                image="kitchen"+kitchenname+"/"+i+".jpg";

                                //alert($(this).find('img').attr('data-bgimg'));
                                //alert($(this).find('img').data('bgimg'));

                                $(this).find('img').attr('data-bgimg',image);
                                $(this).find('img').attr('src',image);
                                i++;


                        });

                            test();

                        });


        });
    </script>
```

Now on ready my test function is executing  but i have same click event within test function

```
   function test() {    
          jQuery('#bf_dishes > li > a').live('click', function(e) {
         // dosomeythisng;
        });
    }
```

but when i click on bf_dishes it runs  that event which is in test function. i want to execute previous click event .

Thanks

Comment: i have no idea why are you doing such a thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   function test() {    
          jQuery('#bf_dishes > li > a').trigger('click');
    }
```

you can trigger `'#bf_dishes > li > a'`
 `click` function from `test()` but it will lead to a infinite loop . an also i think you can't define two click events for the same element in two places ,

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/